# New to Python - how to define sprite

Tags: python, sprite

Trying to get started on programming in python.  we have typed

```
class GridSquare(sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self, position,gridSize)
```

Try to run and it says

```
NameError: name 'sprite' is not defined
```

Sure this must be really simple but cant find the fix.  Can anyone help?

Comment: 1) Its `__init__(..)`. Two underscores instead of one. 2) There is a `:` at the end of function definition. Like: `def __init__(..):`. 3) You will probably have to `import sprite` somehow in your code so as to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you haven't `import`ed sprite explicitly.

```
from pygame import sprite
```

Alternatively, if you already `import pygame`, use

```
class GridSquare(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
```

Also, note that `"_init_" != "__init__"` and you are missing a colon `:`:

```
class GridSquare(sprite.Sprite): # or pygame.sprite.Sprite
    def __init__(self, position, gridSize):
      # ^ note underscores                ^ and colon
```